# Light box with asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms, lightbox

I am trying to dynamicly have 3 images that will be implemented with light box...

i have the LB script in the basemaster as well as the style sheet.

This is my mark up...

```
<div class="gallery">
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkImage1" rel="Gallery" CssClass="lightbox">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImage1" AlternateText=" " />
        </asp:HyperLink>

        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkImage2" rel="Gallery" CssClass="lightbox">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImage2" AlternateText=" " />
        </asp:HyperLink>

        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkImage3" rel="Gallery" CssClass="lightbox">
            <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgImage3" AlternateText=" " />
        </asp:HyperLink>
```

The images display in a fresh window but not in the pop up lightbox...

Any help would be so amazing!

Comment: can you post the jquery code how you are calling the lightbox in your markup or js file whatever

Comment: or the name of the plugin you use for the lightbox.